# How to debug my android aplication with my phone Allview P5

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

I open the list with http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, however I don't see Allview in the list. How can I debug an android application with eclipse - Allview P5?

Comment: doest `adb devices`show your device? If it does, you don't need to add the USB Vendor ID

Answer (score 2):

You must install an adb driver, and since Allview does not have one ( I experienced the same problem ) you have to use an universal one:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

This worked perfectly for me (I own a P6 Stony).

Answer (score 1):

**USB Debugging** should be enabled. You may find that option in `Settings`>`Developer options` in some phones and in `Settings`> `Applications` in some others phones(basically the option will be present in settings somewhere if its available on the phone so please check thoroughly). Secondly not all phones have this functionality so check first whether it has. Also check if your devices device drivers are installed properly. if not reinstall them. finally do Check whether your `Android SDK` is up to date. if not, then update it.

If USB Debugging option is not available. You can still install your app on such phones with the help of `ADB` which stands for `Android Debug Bridge`. for this connect your phone via the USB cable provided. Once the device is recognised. Open your command prompt and type

> adb devices

if you see your phone listed there then type

> adb install your_location/your_file.apk

But in this case you wont be able to know where your app is crashing. You can just test if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

All device vendors may not provide debugging functionality...

if it is provided then Did you put your device into debug mode? This should be found under `Settings`-> `Applications`->`Development`.

and even Install the USB Driver using Android SDK Manager:

[image: Install the USB Driver using Android SDK Manager]

Comment: Also not all of the USB-cables support debugging. Sounds weird but it is true. I have a cable which I can only use for recharging, not debugging...